# Serializing c# class to JSON string with custom column name

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I have this result

```
{
    "StatusCode": "200",
    "Description": "Success",
    "Data": [
        {
            "Language_Key": "btn_select_country",
            "En_Val": "SELECT COUNTRY",
            "Ar_Val": "اختر الدولة"
        },
        {
            "Language_Key": "btn_continue",
            "En_Val": "CONTINUE",
            "Ar_Val": "استمرار"
        }
      ]
}
```

I would like to achieve below result.

```
{
"StatusCode":"200",
"Description":"Success",
"Data":{
    "btn_select_country":{
          "En_Val":"SELECT COUNTRY",
          "Ar_Val":"اختر الدولة"
    },
    "btn_continue":{
          "En_Val":"CONTINUE",
          "Ar_Val":"استمرار"
    }
  }
}
```

I want Language_Key to replace with column name and with 2 child nodes as EN and AR below is my code

[image]

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please add your code as text to your question (and pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). There are [many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), why images of code are not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you serialize a dictionary where the key is your Language_Key:

```
Dictionary<string, Translation> dict = countryObj
    .ToDictionary(o => o.Language_Key, o => new Translation { Ar_Val = o.Ar_Val, En_Val = o.En_Val});
    
rs.Data =  dict;
json = new JavScriptSerializer().Serialize(rs);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. it work like the way I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JsonProperty Attribute to rename properties after they get serialize.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm